# Date Calculations Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: php, sorting, date

I have a PHP function that finds the first and last dates in an array, so that they can be presented in the form "5 Feb to 4 Mar".

However I have found that sometimes the sequence is broken, so instead of "1 Sep to 2 Nov", I get "1 Sep to 26 Oct, 27 Oct to 2 Nov".

The code is:

```
function daterange($datearray){
if(is_array($datearray)){
$resultArray = array();
$index = -1;
$last = 0;
$textdates = NULL;
foreach ($datearray as $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if (false !== $timestamp) {
        $diff = $timestamp - $last;

        if ($diff > 86400) {
            $index = $index + 1;
            $resultArray[$index][] = $date;
        } elseif ($diff > 0) {
            $resultArray[$index][] = $date;
        } else {
            // Error! dates are not in order from small to large
        }
        $last = $timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the array?  What is first and last (minimum and maximum)?

Comment: This is far too complex.  Just use an array sort, grab the first and last values, and you're done...

Comment: Grabbing first and last values doesn't work if there are gaps in the list of dates in the array. For instance if the dates are 2014-01-10, 2014-01-11, 2014-02-10, 2014-02-11, first and last dates would give "10 Jan to 11 Feb" whereas I need it to give "10 Jan to 11 Jan, 10 Feb to 11 Feb".

Comment: Edited with another solution.  I still didn't feel I had all the info but let me know.

Answer (score 2):

One way given what you have posted:

```
$dates = array_map('strototime', $datearray);
$start = min($dates);
$end   = max($dates);
```

Or if you want the dates from the original array:

```
$dates = array_map('strototime', $datearray);
$start = $datearray[array_search(min($dates), $dates)];
$end   = $datearray[array_search(max($dates), $dates)];
```

After reading your comment here's what I came up with.  It may be able to be simplified more, but here it is:

```
$datearray = array( '2014-01-10', '2014-01-11', '2014-02-10', '2014-02-11' );

$dates = array_map('strtotime', $datearray);
sort($dates);
$dates = array_chunk($dates, 2);

foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo $start = date('d M', reset($date));
    echo $end = date('d M', end($date));
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Even better than the approach I cooked up.

Comment: See my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

The key to finding the pproblem and solution was the particular date that was causing the problem. It's the day when we change from British Summer Time to Greenwich Mean Time, so there are effectively 90000 seconds in the day, not 86400.

By changing the line

```
if ($diff > 86400) {
```

to

```
if ($diff > 90000) {
```

the problem was solved!

In other applications, a similar problem might arise in spring when on one day there are only 82800 seconds in the day.

I hope this might help someone, as a small payback for all the help I've been given by others on here.

Comment: Many problems.  Don't use math for dates like this.